# Tags and Terms for Types of Workflow?

Tags: discussion

SDL Tridion 2013 has Bundle (multi-item) workflow. How should we 1) tag and 2) refer to the editing workflow in previous versions (in question and answer text)?

I've heard a few phrases such as:

- <strike>Legacy workflow</strike> (it's the same engine, only VBScript would be "legacy")
- Classic workflow
- Single-item (editing) workflow

**Preferences on how to distinguish between the two types? Should we wait for the documentation?**

**Update** (thanks, David)--the docs have:

- Bundle workflow
- Task workflow
- Programmatic workflow
- Classic editing workflow

I don't think we need separate tags and accepted Bart's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do we require a specific tag and name, what is wrong with just tagging questions with [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) [workflow](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow) or [2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2013) [workflow](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow), that indicates nicely what version and the question can indicate whether it is related to a editing workflow or bundle workflow?

Then if people start to create tags like [editing-workflow](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing-workflow) or [bundle-workflow](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bundle-workflow) we can always consider to give them a proper wiki description or suggest them as a synonym.

Since we cannot create a taxonomy structure in our tags, I would think it makes most sense to try and keep the amount of tags as low as possible (using synonyms to force alternative namings to be automatically replaced by its parent).

Comment: +1 for a clean approach for the tags. Also updated my question to clarify #2--what to call the types of workflow in question text--which you also answered. I'm just glad it wasn't "Workflow Update for Tridion 2013." ;-)

Comment: 2013 + workflow doesn't mean that they are using Bundles. But I imagine that the question itself would make that clear anyway, so I see no reason to create more tags for that.

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, hate that "Legacy workflow" term. As far as I know, the only legacy thing in 2013's implementation of workflow is VBScript automatic activities. All processes are running under the same workflow engine.

If you wanted a definitive list for the different types of workflow there's a pretty good page in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_3378D6AF878142739A0E87E529D81B39).

Comment: Perfect, so we have: `Bundle workflow`, `Task workflow`, `Programmatic workflow`, and `Classic editing workflow`.  No "Legacy." :-) I'll update my question.